# Mysql not summing values inputted through php into table

Tags: php, mysql, sum

So I've got a strange problem.  I have a sum query in php.  If the values are inserted directly into the table via me through phpmyadmin the query works and it sums the values.  If the value is inserted through php script mysql does not sum the value.

In this example, ID 3 to ID 28 I inserted into the table with the insert function.  ID 29 was inserted through my php script and it is not being summed.  I tested this a few times to make sure that that is the problem.

```
SELECT sum(Qty) as LeaveTotal FROM ptrLeave WHERE EmployeeCode = 'PW00' and LeaveType = 1 and Comment != 'Leave Assigned'
```

Hopefully someone can help me please.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling that the PW00 in the row inserted by PHP contains a hidden character or something that is making it be missed by the select statement. If you run a select * statement where EmployeeCode = 'PW00' does ID=29 show up?

Comment: could you show your php script through which you are inserting your data?

Comment: Hi you are correct if I run the sql statment it does not show ID 29 ... wonder what I did wrong but will start digging there

Comment: @Moudi thank you I had to trim the values I inputted into the table.